# Upgrading SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2014, will my .NET web applications have any issues?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Several .NET 4.5 web applications using EF 6 were originally mapped to SQL Server 2008. If we upgrade to SQL Server 2014, will my .NET web application have issues (AS-IS)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is No. It should not have any issue upgrading from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2014.

You do not need to recompile the code. As the result, EF will still generate queries compatible with SQL Server 2008, and will not take the advantage of SQL Server 2014's new features.

**FYI:** Not the other way around. Downgrading might break for some queries, since ProviderManifestToken is different.